# JS Array in a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

This piece of code will print `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` on the console it means in every iteration arr.length change and this is reflected in the loop body also.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
for (e of arr) {
  arr.push(arr[arr.length - 1] + 1);
  if (arr.length >= 10) break;
}
console.log(arr)
```

But here, The output will be `[4,5,6]` and that mean the shift() function is not considering the expansion of the array.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
for (e of arr) {
  arr.push(arr[arr.length - 1] + 1);
  if (arr[arr.length - 1] >= 10) break;
  arr.shift();
}
console.log(arr)
```

My question is why? I expected `[8,9,10]` output from second code

Comment: I would suggest you to remove `arr.shift()` and use `arr = arr.slice(-4,-1)` instead

Comment: your array doesnt go beyond 3 elemetns in the second case. so in the first iteration its e=1 , second e=3, third e=5. can visualize with https://pythontutor.com/javascript.html if u want

Comment: If you `console.log(arr)` immediately _after_ `arr.shift();` you'll see what's happening.

Comment: The issue has been identified above, but as an aside, mutating an array as you iterate through it is generally a really bad idea.

Comment: Thank you guys I just understand I expected the for..loop work with value instead of index!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan So what is a good way when I want to make a tree beside iterate an array through itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you have add element at first,then you invoke `shift()` to remove the element,so the array size will not change and it will only iterate once

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
for (e of arr) {
  arr.push(arr[arr.length - 1] + 1); // add element
  if (arr[arr.length - 1] >= 10) break;
  arr.shift(); // remove element
}
console.log(arr)
```

In order to get your expected result,we need to make sure it can iterate more than once until got the expected result. So we can change `for` to `while`

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
while(arr.at(-1) < 10) {
  arr.push(arr.at(-1) + 1);
  arr.shift();
}
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: @pilchard Glad to see you again and thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1):

The second `for ...of` loop is working correctly:

```
  let arr = [1, 2, 3];

  for (e of arr) {
    arr.push(arr[arr.length - 1] + 1); // 4, 5, 6
    if (arr[arr.length - 1] >= 10) break; // false, false, false
    arr.shift(); // 1, 2, 3
  }

  console.log(arr); // [ 4, 5, 6 ]
```

Because you are removing the first element of the array in each loop with `shift()`, your array never exceeds 3 elements at the beginning of the loop, so it will only loop 3 times.

hope this helps.